# How to create new lists with iterator as list name?

Tags: python, list, loops, syntax-error

I'm using Python 2.7, and I am trying to develop a function which has the capability of reading a csv file and creating an empty list for each column. In other words, use an index iterator to concatenate 'col' with the iterator, thus creating a unique empty list for each column, e.g. empty lists named col1, col2, col3, col4, etc. My problem:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

from the last line in:

```
my_file = open( r'{}'.format( file_path ) )

for i, line in enumerate( my_file ):
    if i >= 1:
        row = line.split( ',' )

col_N = len( line.split( ',' ) )   

for i in range( 0, col_N ):
    j = i + 1
    'col{}'.format( j ) = []
```

Comment: no good reason to name the variable after the index name if you don't know it ahead of time.  Just make a dictionary of lists, and use the names as keys...

Comment: (OT) Your code formatting is ugly. Check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
'col{}'.format( j )
```

is a string. Not a variable. You can't assign it a value.

---

To add your dinamic variable to the globals:

```
globals()['col{}'.format(j)] = []
```

Then use it regularly with name supplied by you, or as `globals()['col{}'.format(j)]` if j is dinamic.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want these new variables necessarily go into the global namespace you can use exec:

```
exec('col{}'.format( j ) + '= []')
```